# Identify a PDF/A file in PHP

Tags: php, shell, pdf

I'm trying to identify if a PDF file is a PDF/A file. Using poppler-php, I'm able to read the metadata but there are no signs showing it's a PDF/A file.

My goal is to edit PDFs by adding data to them. PDF/A seem to be read only (Since they are designed for archiving, it's no surprise). I want to identify them in order to refuse them in advance.

Regards,

Comment: How do you want to edit the PDFs exactly? If you are able to do this, you should also be able to access the metadata of the document and check them for PDF/A related information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so i've managed with a "simple" solution : When uploaded, I just edit the PDF (with a small, 1px transparent square). If I catch an exception during the process, I refuse the PDF.